# Installing Postgres driver in php7-fpm Docker container

Tags: php, postgresql, docker

I've installed `PHP:latest` Docker container using the docker-compose command. It installed `php-7.1.6-fpm` in my Docker. When I tried to install `php7-pgsql` extension it failed to find that package, instead found `pdo` and `pdo_pgsql` packages. That will not satisfy my need. When I search for the available packages in the installed PHP container, I could not find any related pgsql packages for `php7`, instead, I saw `php5-pgsql` package, that will not work with php7-fpm.

Finally, I installed php-5.6-fpm container after removing the old one targeting to use `php5-pgsql` package. But now I disappointed again that I could not find `php5-pgsql` package in the newly installed container.

I know I'll be missing some important points. Whether Alpine Linux does not have `php-pgsql` extension. What are the possible ways to include this extension in my PHP container. I've also included Nginx and Postgres in my docker-compose.yml

I've only 3-day theory knowledge in Docker and first-day practical experience.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/348 it works when we run it inside the container, but Dockerfile is not working. couldn't find the reason

Answer (score 25):

I ran into the same issue when I was settings up a new project to use pgsql.

I am using php7, so you should be able to use it as well. On your Dockerfile ensure you're covering the following steps.

Ensure you have the dependencies installed:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev
```

Configure the extension:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql
```

Install the extension:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql
```

Comment: What exactly does configuring do and why is it necessary?

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question i know, but i ran into this today and believe the above solution has changed with php:7.4-fpm-alpine

So where it used to be:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev
```

Should now be:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-dev
```

Hopefully this helps anyone that runs into the same issue.

Comment: in my case in php-fpm-alpine, I `RUN apk … postgresql-dev && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql` <-- adding pgsql if you want use `pg_connect` in PHP